# What does filterApplyIdx mean in parse.js?

Tags: swig-template

I'm working on swig.js to make it work with Django more friendly,I can understand most of the codes but the parse.js,I wonder what the 'filterApplyIdx' exactly means.Is there anybody else working on this too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I posted to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swig-templates/ytwcBfZSpMQ)

`filterApplyIdx` is an array of indices on the `out` (output) array at which filters will be applied. When the parser finds a filter it will apply it to the `out` array at the index of the last value in `filterApplyIdx`.

For example: if the `out` array has the following `['(', 'my_var']`, the `filterApplyIdx` should be `[0, 1]`. (it will apply first to `my_var`, and second to everything that is encompassed by the opening parenthesis, once the closing parenthesis is found). So, if the next item parsed is a filter, it will pop the `filterApplyIdx` last value, which is `1`, and look at the `out` array, and apply the filter to the token at `out[1]`.

If, however, the `out` array was something more complex, like: `['my_func(', 'foo', 'bar']` (note that the closing parenthesis for `my_func` has not been found yet), the `filterApplyIdx` will be: `[0, 2]`. We've removed `1` now because the chance to apply a filter to `foo` has passed, since a new variable, `bar` was found.